# Adding a legend to a plot with two data frames using ggplot2 (r)

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm trying to plot **the median heart rate of boys & girls per minute** in a PE lesson to see if there are some gender differences. I'd like to plot **2 line graphs using ggplot2** in two different colours representing the gender.
My problem is, I'm using **two different data frames** and I'm not able to **add a legend** that shows "green = boys, red = girls".

Here are my data frames: wDaten2809HR & mDaten2809HR.

That's the current code for my plot which does not show any legend:

```
ggplot(NULL, aes(x= minute, y= meanHR))+
  geom_line(data= wDaten2809HR, color= "orangered2", size= 0.7)+
  geom_line(data= mDaten2809HR, color= "seagreen3", size= 0.7)+
  scale_x_continuous(expand= c(0, 0), limits = c(0,35), breaks= c
                     (0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35), name= "Zeit [min]")+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(70, 90, 110, 130, 150, 170, 190, 210), limits= c(70, 210), name = "Herzrate [BPM]")+
  theme_grey()+
  labs(title = "Geschlechtervergleich - durchschnittliche Herzrate",
       subtitle = "28.09.2021")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 12, color = "black", hjust = 0.5),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 10, color = "grey50", hjust = 0.5), legend.position = "bottom")
```

I can see the plot showing the two graphs but no legend due to the two data frames. I've tried a lot different things that were explained on coding websites to manually add a legend but I'm lost, nothing works. Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Can you provide your data or embed the image of your current graph?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easiest if you do some data manipulation first in order to combine the two data frames. You can use `mutate()` in this case. Then you can specify that the colour of the lines should represent the `gender` column.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_boys <- data.frame(
  time = c(1:10),
  heart_rate = c(100:109)
)
df_girls <- data.frame(
  time = c(1:10),
  heart_rate = c(105:114)
)

df <- bind_rows(
  df_boys %>% mutate(gender = "M"),
  df_girls %>% mutate(gender="F")
)


ggplot(df, aes(x=time, y=heart_rate, group=gender)) + 
  geom_line(aes(colour=gender))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This solution intents to create manually the legend specifiyng inside `aes()` of `geom_line()` a legend id and then refering them in `scale_colour_manual()`

```
ggplot(NULL, aes(x= minute, y= meanHR))+
  geom_line(data= wDaten2809HR, 
            aes(color = "woman"),
            size= 0.7)+
  geom_line(data= mDaten2809HR, 
            aes(color = "man"),
            size= 0.7)+
  scale_x_continuous(expand= c(0, 0), 
                     limits = c(0,35), 
                     breaks= c(0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35), name= "Zeit [min]")+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(70, 90, 110, 130, 150, 170, 190, 210),
                     limits= c(70, 210),
                     name = "Herzrate [BPM]")+
  scale_color_manual(name='Legend name',
                     breaks=c('woman', 'man'),
                     values=c('woman'='orangered2', 
                              'man'='seagreen3')) +
  theme_grey()+
  labs(title = "Geschlechtervergleich - durchschnittliche Herzrate",
       subtitle = "28.09.2021")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 12,
                                  color = "black", 
                                  hjust = 0.5),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 10, 
                                     color = "grey50", 
                                     hjust = 0.5), 
        legend.position = "bottom")
```